# how to give gridview first column left margin from gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUploadedFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
                    PageSize="7" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowEditing="grdUploadedFiles_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdUploadedFiles_RowUpdating"
                    OnRowCancelingEdit="grdUploadedFiles_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="grdUploadedFiles_RowDeleting"
                    ShowFooter="True" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
                    Width="439px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                     Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Arial" CellPadding="3" BorderWidth="1px">
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileType") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
                            <ItemStyle/>
                        </asp:CommandField></column></gridview>
```

I am using above code for my gridview.and i want to give padding to my 1st column.and also i want to give underline to my edit and delete link in my gridview.For that if i give textuderline='true" on editing it shows Update Delete both a single underline which looks ugly.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest using CSS selectors for styling instead of using control properties (that generates inline styling that are difficult to maintain/change) - assuming you have applied css class "myGridView" to your grid view then use CSS such as

```
table.myGridView
{
  color: black;
  border: solid 1px #999999;
  background-color: white;
  width: 439px;
  font-family: arial;
}

table.myGridView th
{
  // style your column headings
}

table.myGridView td
{
  // style your cells
  padding: 3px;
}

table.myGridView tr td:first-child
{
  // style the first cell in each row
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```